# Incompatible Pointers in =

Tags: c, error-handling

I do not know how to get around this error. I must not be assigning the same type. Keep receiving an '(strict) incompatible pointers in ='

```
#define POOLSZ 53
typedef struct{
     int eventnr;
     int eventfq;
     struct olnode *next;
}olnode;

olnode pool[POOLSZ];
olnode *avail

void initpool()
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < POOLSZ-1; i++)
        pool[i].next = &pool[i+1]; /*This is the error line */
    pool[i].next = NULL;
    avail = pool;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line makes a pointer to `struct olnode`:

```
struct olnode *next;
```

But you don't define such struct. You only have an anonymous struct, `typedef`ed to `olnode`.

Fix:

```
typedef struct olnode {...} olnode;
```

Comment: I didn't catch that, quick eyes.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I didn't see it at the first glance too, had to actually compile it and look at error messages.